# error in plm regression

Tags: r, panel-data

colleagues! I have panel data:

```
    Company year       Beta     NI   Sales  Export Hedge      FL     QR     AT Foreign
1       1 2010 -2.2052800 293000 1881000 78.6816     0 23.5158  1.289 0.6554    3000
2       1 2011 -2.2536069 316000 2647000 81.4885     0 21.7945 1.1787 0.8282   22000
3       1 2012  0.3258693 363000 2987000 82.4908     0 24.5782 1.2428  0.813  -11000
4       1 2013  0.4006030 549000 4546000 79.4325     0 31.4168 0.6038 0.7905   71000
5       1 2014 -0.4508811 348000 5376000 79.2411     0 37.1451 0.6563  0.661  -64000
6       1 2015  0.1494696 355000 5038000 77.1735     0 33.3852 0.9798 0.5483   37000
```

But R shows the mistake when I try to use plm package for the regression:

```
panel <- read.csv("Panel.csv",  header=T, sep=";")
p=plm(data=panel,Beta~NI, model="within",index=c("id","year"))


Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
  duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)

3: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
```

I searched this error in the Internet and read that it's connected with the id of company and year. But I did not find the way how to avoid this problem. Also, when I do na.omit(panel), R does not show the error, but it's significant to stay NA data and companies in the data. Please, tell me to do with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Let consider the `Produc` dataset in the `plm` package.

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
head(Produc)

    state year region     pcap     hwy   water    util       pc   gsp    emp unemp
1 ALABAMA 1970      6 15032.67 7325.80 1655.68 6051.20 35793.80 28418 1010.5   4.7
2 ALABAMA 1971      6 15501.94 7525.94 1721.02 6254.98 37299.91 29375 1021.9   5.2
3 ALABAMA 1972      6 15972.41 7765.42 1764.75 6442.23 38670.30 31303 1072.3   4.7
4 ALABAMA 1973      6 16406.26 7907.66 1742.41 6756.19 40084.01 33430 1135.5   3.9
5 ALABAMA 1974      6 16762.67 8025.52 1734.85 7002.29 42057.31 33749 1169.8   5.5
6 ALABAMA 1975      6 17316.26 8158.23 1752.27 7405.76 43971.71 33604 1155.4   7.7
```

In this dataset information are collected over time (17 years) and over the same sample units (48 US States).

```
table(Produc$state, Produc$year)
                 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986
  ALABAMA           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
  ARIZONA           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
  ARKANSAS          1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
  CALIFORNIA        1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
  ...
```

`plm` requires that each (state, year) pair be unique.

```
any(table(Produc$state, Produc$year)!=1)
[1] FALSE
```

The command `plm` works nicely with this dataset:

```
plmFit1 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
summary(plmFit1)


Oneway (individual) effect Within Model
Call:
plm(formula = log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
    data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"))

Balanced Panel: n=48, T=17, N=816

Residuals :
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.12000 -0.02370 -0.00204  0.01810  0.17500 

Coefficients :
             Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
log(pcap) -0.02614965  0.02900158 -0.9017    0.3675    
log(pc)    0.29200693  0.02511967 11.6246 < 2.2e-16 ***
log(emp)   0.76815947  0.03009174 25.5273 < 2.2e-16 ***
unemp     -0.00529774  0.00098873 -5.3582 1.114e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    18.941
Residual Sum of Squares: 1.1112
R-Squared:      0.94134
Adj. R-Squared: 0.93742
F-statistic: 3064.81 on 4 and 764 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Now we duplicate one of the (state, year) pairs:

```
 Produc[2,2] <- 1970
 any(table(Produc$state, Produc$year)>1)
 [1] TRUE
```

and `plm` now generates the same error message that you described above:

```
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
      data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))

Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
  duplicate couples (id-time)
Inoltre: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)

3: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: A table of an unbalanced panel without duplicates has zero values, therefore I suggest to use `any(table(Produc$state, Produc$year) > 1)`.

Comment: Then how can I identify the duplicate rows in the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered another case that warns of `duplicate couples (id-time)` although there are none, and which might be worth sharing here.

Namely, if you try to name the time variable `"id"` for some reason.

```
library(plm)
data(Produc)

## duplicate time variable and name it "id"
Produc <- transform(Produc, id=year)

## check duplicate couples (id-time)
stopifnot(!any(table(Produc[, "state"], Produc[, "id"]) > 1))

f1 <- plm(gsp ~ pcap, Produc, index=c("state", "year"), model="within", effect="twoways")
## OK

f2 <- plm(gsp ~ pcap, Produc, index=c("state", "id"), model="within", effect="twoways")
# Warning messages:
# 1: In pdata.frame(x, index) :
#   duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
#  to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
# 2: In is.pbalanced.default(id, time) : duplicate couples (id-time)
```

The reason gets visible, when we explicitly create plm panel data frames, which `plm :plm` internally does if you don't provide one.

```
## create pdata.frames
p1 <- pdata.frame(Produc, index=c("state", "year"))
p2 <- pdata.frame(Produc, index=c("state", "id"))

head(index(p1))
#     state year
# 1 ALABAMA 1970
# 2 ALABAMA 1971
# 3 ALABAMA 1972
# 4 ALABAMA 1973
# 5 ALABAMA 1974
# 6 ALABAMA 1975

head(index(p2))
#     state state.1
# 1 ALABAMA ALABAMA
# 2 ALABAMA ALABAMA
# 3 ALABAMA ALABAMA
# 4 ALABAMA ALABAMA
# 5 ALABAMA ALABAMA
# 6 ALABAMA ALABAMA
```

As we can see, `"id"` is not used as a variable, but somehow associated with the column `"state"`. Though I am not sure, what exactly goes wrong, since `all.equal(str(p1), str(p2))` throws  `TRUE`.

Comment: "id", "time", and "group" are column names internally used for indexes. If they refer to an index with a different meaning than the name implies, things get messy. The development version has a warning for this, see NEWS.md: "index: gives warning if argument 'which' contains "confusing" values.
  "confusing": an index variable called by user 'id', 'time', or 'group' if it
  does not refer to the respective index (e.g., time index variable is called 'id'
  in the user's data frame)."

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks for informing, I should have put this as a ticket on Github. Please let me know when the new version of this _great_ package is released and I can delete the answer.

Comment: new version is released since quite a while

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks, it now throws at least the announced warning.